# Warning: mysql_query(): 7 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource

Tags: php, mysql, resources, hyperlink

Similar questions to this my have been asked a lot of times before. But since I did not find a solution in any of the questions asked before me, I take the liberty of asking it again.

My program uses a class made by me which handles all database connections for the program. Several modules I've used before used the same class without fail but when I chose to do a new module using the same class, the warning shows as-

Warning: mysql_query(): 7 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in *wherever...* on line 49.

The warning happens when I execute a MySQL query through a function I made. The function is as follows-

```
public function runquery($_query)
{
  $result = mysql_query($_query,$this -> connection); //line 49
  if (! $result) die(mysql_error());
  else return $result;
}
```

The function belongs to a class named `mysql` and it has not been tampered with or made changes to. So the function should technically work as expected, as every other module relying on the same class for database connectivity works just fine.

The query execution is successful however and I manage to update tables with no problems (except the warning). The block of code in the main program where the `runquery()` function is called from is as follows-

```
$phpmyadmin = new mysql();
$phpmyadmin->connect('localhost', 'root', '');
$phpmyadmin->setdb('test_db');
$result = $phpmyadmin->runquery($Query);
unset($phpmyadmin);
```

So the `mysql`'s functions work just as fine as ever and the query executes just fine. But the warning shows for a reason I cannot understand. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symptoms suggest that the database connection has been closed or dropped. Look for unwanted [mysql_close()](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php) calls in your code. Additionally, you can use the following functions to troubleshoot the issue:

1. [is_resource()](http://es.php.net/is_resource) and [get_resource_type()](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.get-resource-type.php) to confirm that `$this->connection` is a valid data type.
2. [mysql_ping()](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php) to find out if the database connection is alive.

If it's a rare issue, log stuff into a file and wait until it happens again.

Comment: `echo is_resource($this -> connection);` gives 1 `echo get_resource_type($this -> connection);` gives mysql link

Comment: mysql_ping() however gives that- `Warning: mysql_ping() [function.mysql-ping]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_db\cpanel\include\scripts\php\mysql.php on line 49

Warning: mysql_ping() [function.mysql-ping]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_db\cpanel\include\scripts\php\mysql.php on line 49

Warning: mysql_query(): 7 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_db\cpanel\include\scripts\php\mysql.php on line 50
Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: Do you have a passwordless user called "ODBC"? *(Please use `var_dump()` to inspect variables; `echo` will cast everything to string.)*

Comment: G. Vicario // You were correct to think that there was a problem with database connectivity. I had indeed, left a mysql connection not initiated after I closed it. This I found out after a through re-inspection of the code.

Comment: mysql_close() fixed my end!

Answer (score 0):

There should not be spaces.

```
$result = mysql_query($_query,$this->connection);
```

Comment: It works just as fine with spaces. But even without them the warning does not go away. I reckon the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @SamikSengupta What is the result of `var_dump($this->connection);`?

Comment: `var_dump($this->connection);` gives `resource(7) of type (mysql link)`